# Including PLplot in a C project

Tags: c, include, cmake

I am working on a C project I downloaded from the Internet, and I need to use some `PLplot` functions for visualization.
However, I am quite new to both `PLplot` and `cmake`, and I need help to modify the `CMakeLists.txt` file accordingly.

I tried adding the following in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, but it didn't work (failed to find `PLplot`):

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(PLPLOT REQUIRED plplot)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PLPLOT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${PLPLOT_LIBRARY_DIRS})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main ${PLPLOT_LIBRARIES})
```

I also tried to define the paths manually as follows:

```
SET(PLPLOT_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/local/PLplot/include/plplot")
SET(PLPLOT_LIBRARY_DIRS "/usr/local/PLplot/lib")
```

but it is still failing, I guess because I didn't define `PLPLOT_LIBRARIES` which I don't know what it is

Note that on the laptop I am working on (running Kubuntu OS), `PLplot` is installed under `/usr/local/PLplot`

Comment: i don't know what `PLplot` is, but did you try providing the path to the compilar?`-L`, `-I` switches?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I have little experience here, but I thought that the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `LINK_DIRECTORIES` lines in `CMakeLists.txt` will lead to creation of a makefile with the appropriate `-I` and `-L`, isn't that the case? I am only trying to modify the existing `CMakeLists` file to include `PLplot`; I'm not writing a makefile from scratch

Comment: sorry, I don't know that for sure. but just in case, can you edit the Makefile manually before complation[hope that's possible] and add those points?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The generated Makefile is quite lengthy and I don't have enough experience and skill to modify it. I was hoping to adjust the `CMakeLists.txt` file instead. My problem (I guess) should get solved if I either define `${PLPLOT_LIBRARIES}` manually or let Cmake find all `PLplot` related stuff automatically... I don't know how to do either. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Not sure the liscense, but you could try https://github.com/mrquincle/polychronization/blob/master/cmake/FindPLplot.cmake. (Usually when I have trouble integrating a package I use google FindX.cmake, if its popular enough someone has provided it)